# dynamic Auto Layout resize

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift4

I have a container with a `UITextView` inside it. The container is supposed to resize according to the height of the text view. I'm currently using there lines to make it work

```
 let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let textViewHeight = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)

    containerView.frame.size = textViewHeight
```

The thing is, i'm using Auto Layout on the rest of the constraints and I would like to manage this as an Auto Layout as well.
I've tried using `.greatestFiniteMagnitude` in my auto layout but that didn't do much for me.

Comment: Constrain all 4 sides of the text view to its container view. Disable scrolling for the text view. It should auto-size to its content. No size calculations needed.

Comment: @DonMag I feel stupid now, I deleted the constraint and it still worked perfectly. Apparently i've added all 4 constraints to my textview earlier. Thank you! Will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the layout and constraints to allow the text field to auto-size and auto-expand its containing view.

The containerView (blue) is constrained Top/Leading/Trailing, but ***not*** Bottom or Height.

The textView is constrained Top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom, all at `8`, and Scrolling is Disabled.

Small amount of text:
[image]

Longer amount of text:
[image]

At run-time, when you set the text -- *or* when typing in the field -- its Height will auto-size based on the amount of text.